# Increment pointer of byte array in C#

Tags: c#, c++, arrays, pointers, unsafe

I have a `byte[] data` in which I don't need first element. Array is quiet big, so I don't want to copy it to another array (`payload`) as shown below.

`Buffer.BlockCopy(data, 1, payload, 0, count);`

In C++ I can just increment pointer of array to move poiner.

```
int main()
{
    char* data= "!Hello, World!";
    data++;
    std::cout << data<< std::endl;
}
```

This part of code prints "Hello, World!". How I can do the same in C#? Maybe to use unsafe code?

Comment: Use a span by slicing the array, `data.Slice(1)` will create a `Span<byte>` starting at index 1 of the array and ending at its last element.

Comment: You might need to cast the array as a `Span<byte>` first, I don't know if it's implied. So it should be `((Span<byte>)data).Slice(1);`. This will _not_ cause a copy it's essentially a safe pointer to the array.

Comment: [Modern (C#8) slicing is using `[1..]`.](https://www.codejourney.net/2019/02/csharp-8-slicing-indexes-ranges/)

Comment: also, indexing into a `Span<T>` should be as fast as indexing into an array, if efficiency matters. It is a direct pointer as opposed to `ArraySegment<T>` which stores a reference to the array _and_ an offset/boundary.

Answer (score 2):

[You can slice arrays in c#8 using `[1..]`.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/proposals/csharp-8.0/ranges)

```cs
var data = new char[] {'!','H','e','l','l','o',' ','W','o','r','l','d','!'};
foreach(var ch in data[1..]) Console.Write(ch);
Console.WriteLine();
```

gives:
Hello World!

Answer (score 0):

Arrays have immutable length, so either start your loops and whatnot from index 1 instead of 0 or copy it to another one